# Example of a global derivation on $[0,\infty)$ that is not a vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am self studying Differential Geometry. I want to find an example of a global derivation on $[0,\infty)$ that is not a vector field. But I am having trouble coming up with an example.

My definitions: Let $M$ be a manifold (possibly with boundary). A global derivation on $M$ is a linear map $f:C^\infty(M)\to C^\infty(M)$ that satisfies Leibniz' Rule. A vector field on $M$ is a global derivation that admits a local flow at every point.

Anything helps!

Comment: The derivation formally corresponding to the vector field $-\frac{d}{dt}$ (which has no local flow at $0$)...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Andy, I don't think we need the negative sign, since (to the best of my knowledge) flows are usually defined on $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$.

Comment: @Ted: Ah, right. Clearly I've thought too much about flows with people in dynamical systems (who often restrict to forward time). :)